# Подключение весов через RS232

Tags: delphi, rs232

Привет. Необходимо к имеющемуся проекту подключить снятие информации (постоянное) с весов, имеющих RS232. Никогда не работал с внешним оборудованием. Подскажите, в какую сторону двигаться?

Answer (score 1):

Вся работа в этом случае сводится к работе с Com-портом. У весов есть набор команд (обычно в текстовом виде), разобраться с которыми не оч сложно. Первое, с чего нужно начать - научиться работать с портом. Вот [пример](http://www.delphisources.ru/files/sources/system/2010-year/comport-library.zip).

Comment: Получится отправлять сообщения, помогу и с командами. Сам когда то лепил для весов и принтера чеков.

Answer (score 0):

Есть либа для CAS LP15, как раз на Delph.